# Weblink with JCE add &task=weblink.go

Tags: joomla-3.x, weblinks

If I add a weblink via JCE the link will be added with `&task=weblink.go`

For what is it, and in wich file will this evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "task" is a [class method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.properties-methods) (function) in a component's controller.

In your case, `weblink` is the controller and `go` is a method within the controller.

Here is a simple and clear tutorial: [How to add a New Task to your Joomla 3 Component](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/create-component/add-new-task) from InmotionHosting.

I'll bring the screen captured snippets into text here, but certainly visit the link for the tutorial.

@ **/components/com_helloworld/helloworld.php**

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
define('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by HelloWorld
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('HelloWorld');

// Perform the Request task
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$controller->execute($input->getCmd('task'));

// Display the name of the task being executed
echo "<p>Just finished executing: " , $input->getCmd('task') , "</p>";

// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();
```

@ **/components/com_helloworld/controller.php**

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
define('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

/**
 * Hello World Component Controller
 */
class HelloWorldController extends JControllerLegacy
{
    function shout()
    {
        echo "<p>THIS IS ME SHOUTING!</p>";
    }
}
```

The effect at **example.com/index.php/option=com_helloworld&task=shout** would be:

> THIS IS ME SHOUTING!
>   Just finished executing: shout

with the generated source code looking like:

```
<p>THIS IS ME SHOUTING!</p>
<p>Just finished executing: shout</p>
```

For supplemental reading:

- [what is difference between view and task in joomla 2.5 and what is url structure in joomla 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19029807/2943403)
- [MVC what stage sets a task if none provided](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23700/12352)
- [$input->getCmd('task') what is 'task' in JOOMLA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19195163/2943403)